# SCP from GitLab pipeline fails (Permission denied)

Tags: ssh, gitlab, pipeline

I need to scp some files from a gitlab pipeline to a server. Here are the steps I took to accomplish this, and the error I've received.

On my local machine, I create a public and private key to use specifically for this, and nothing else.  The private key is for a variable in my gitlab pipeline, and the public key goes in the server's authorized key files.:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "Pipeline"


Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_pipeline
```

This creates the public (`id_rsa_pipeline.pub`) and private (`id_rsa_pipeline`) key successfully.

I then add the key to the remote server:

```
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa_temp user@server.com

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "id_rsa_pipeline.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'user@server.com'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

I then test the login, using the key `ssh -i id_rsa_pipeline user@server.com`, and it works as expected. No issues logging in using key, without password.

I then add a variable in my pipeline named `IDENTITY`.

My stage that does the work in my pipeline has a `before_script` like this.

```
  before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$IDENTITY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

My scp command I'm using in the pipeline looks like this:

```
after_script:
    - scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null /path/to/my/file.txt user@development:/home/user/
```

When I run the pipeline, I'm getting the following:

```
Running after script...
$ scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null /path/to/my/file.txt user@development:/home/user/
Warning: Permanently added 'user,192.168.1.50' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
user@server: Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

Things I've tried:

1. Creating the keys again.
2. Making sure no whitespaces or return characters got into the key when copy/pasting into gitlab.
3. Creating the keys on different servers.
4. Using different users.
5. General googling.

On every user I've tried this with, I can ssh into the server using the key, and I can scp files without passwords using the keys.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: dd u try to add `-v` to the scp command and compare the output with the successful `ssh -v` command?

Comment: Can you add -vvv option in scp command  and check if you see any issue?

Comment: You can try adding the -o IdentityFile=/path/to/private/ssh/key over the afterScript scp command to be precise on which ssh keys has to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the -o IdentityFile=/path/to/private/ssh/key over the afterScript scp command to be precise on which ssh keys has to be used.

Comment: When I ran the verbose output of the scp command, it was trying the correct key, but wouldn't work.  Then, just for fun (because you mentioned it), I tried specifying the key (The exact same path mentioned in the verbose output that it was already using).  That worked for some reason.

Comment: Awesome :D , sometimes happens man, we need to be very specific. Glad this helps. Thanks for the points as well and you are welcome! I ran sometimes scripts like this and sometimes just we need to avoid assumptions and provide details.

Answer (score 2):

For testing, I would:

- create a key pair again, but without passphrase.
- create a new [file type CI/CD variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html). As `Key`, enter the name `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`, and in the `Value` field, paste the *content* of your private key that you created earlier.
- follow the same process as in "[SSH keys when using the Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor)"

```yaml
before_script:
  ##
  ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
  ##
  - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

  ##
  ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  ##
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

  ##
  ## Give the right permissions, otherwise ssh-add will refuse to add files
  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY file type CI/CD variable to the agent store
  ##
  - chmod 400 "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
  - ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"

  ##
  ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
  ##
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

  ##
  ## Optionally, if you will be using any Git commands, set the user name and
  ## and email.
  ##
  # - git config --global user.email "user@example.com"
  # - git config --global user.name "User name"
```

Make sure the private server’s [SSH host keys are verified](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys).

Comment: Thanks, but this provided the same results as I was getting before.  I'm beginning to wonder what the possibilities are that someone did something really strange to this server.  I'm not even sure what could be breaking this at this point.

Comment: @trueCamelType Is there anything suspicious on the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the server? Or in the server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file? Check the server logs (`/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`)